# .htaccess not rewriting url if image location exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file in my DocumentRoot

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However, if the user tries to go to the url `/images/1/image.png` then they are shown the image, rather than the request being re-written and sent to index.php with `1` and `image.png` as `$_GET` parameters.

Is there any way to change this so that if any user paths directly to an existing image they are directed to a my index.php file instead, as I want to handle routing and check for permissions before displaying this image first.

Note: I don't want to simply deny access, I just want to route away from the image, where I can then check permissions and then display it if permissions are correct.

Comment: `-f` tests if the requested url is a file that exists. `!-f` basically requires that the url not exist, so any image which DOES exist is excluded by the rule.

Comment: @MarcB I tried that, but my CSS/JS files stopped loading, presumably because they were being re-written, which is why I needed that !-f rule in the firstplace, cheers for clearing that up though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` avoids rewriting any existing files.

Comment: This seems to stop my CSS files loading, is there any way to apply this to only this `/images` directory? Apart from that, looks promising.

Comment: @Jackhardcastle yes place it in your images directory and leave your other one in your root and add a `/` infront of `index.php?`

Comment: @Jackhardcastle: Try my updated rule now assuming you don't have any .htaccess in `images/` directory.

Comment: I'll give that a go and get back to you shortly, cheers for that ^^.